# How to stop timer after the the countdown is over

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Countdown</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
// set minutes
var mins = 1;

// calculate the seconds (don't change this! unless time progresses at a different speed for you...)
var secs = mins * 60;
function countdown() {
    setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);
}
function Decrement() {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
        seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
        // if less than a minute remaining
        if (seconds < 59) {
            seconds.value = secs;
        } else {
            minutes.value = getminutes();
            seconds.value = getseconds();
        }
        secs--;
        setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);
    }
}
function getminutes() {
    // minutes is seconds divided by 60, rounded down
    mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
    return mins;
}
function getseconds() {
    // take mins remaining (as seconds) away from total seconds remaining
    return secs-Math.round(mins *60);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="timer">
    Time Left: 00:<input id="minutes" type="text" style="width: 20px; border: none; background-color:none; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;">:<input id="seconds" type="text" style="width: 26px; border: none; background-color:none; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;">
</div>
<script>
countdown();
</script>
```

In this java script code the timer get executing after the time is over and time goes in minus example (00-1:30).
So I want to stop the timer when it reaches the 00:00. And it should give alert when the time is completed or submit the page.

Comment: you mean this -->  var idx = setTimeout(...);  clearTimeout(idx);  ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp

Comment: just a hint, you can write setTimeout (or setInterval) as: setTimeout(funcName, 1000); --> no quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues, the biggest being that you are testing the `seconds` and not `seconds.value`, so you are always entering the else block.  However, you also don't have a condition for when it reaches zero.  Here is a jsfiddle that should fix those things, http://jsfiddle.net/psQb5/.

Answer (score 0):

use **setInterval()** function instead of **setTimeout()**.
when you want to stop timer using **clearInterval()** function.

for basic understanding of above function click below

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).

Answer (score 0):

there are two possibilities. One is to use the function setInterval instead of setTimeout. Like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// set minutes
var mins = 1;

// calculate the seconds (don't change this! unless time progresses at a different speed for you...)
var secs = mins * 60;
var intervalVar;
function countdown() {
    intervalVar = setInterval('Decrement()',1000);
}
function Decrement() {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
        seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
        // if less than a minute remaining
        if (seconds < 59) {
            seconds.value = secs;
        } else {
            minutes.value = getminutes();
            seconds.value = getseconds();
        }
        secs--;
        if (secs == 0) {
            window.clearTimeout(intervalVar);
            alert('timeout');
        }
    }
}
function getminutes() {
    // minutes is seconds divided by 60, rounded down
    mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
    return mins;
}
function getseconds() {
    // take mins remaining (as seconds) away from total seconds remaining
    return secs-Math.round(mins *60);
}
</script>
```